# Updating data from submission form into MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to update data from a submission form into the MySQL database using PHP. When I click on the button to update the value in the database, it becomes empty.

Additionally, I also receive the following two error messages :

> Notice: Undefined variable: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\test1\edit.php on line 64
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\test1\edit.php on line 66

The following is my PHP Code:

```
<?php

  $name = '';

  if (isset($_GET['editQ'])) {
    $ok = true;
    $id = $_GET['editQ'];

    if ($ok) {
      // add database code here
      $db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'test2015');
      $sql = sprintf("UPDATE question SET question_body='%s'
              WHERE question_id=%s",
      mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $name),$id);
      mysqli_query($db, $sql);
      echo '<p>User updated.</p>';
      mysqli_close($db);
    }
    } else {
      $db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'test2015');
      $sql = sprintf('SELECT * FROM question WHERE question_id=%s', $id);
      $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
      foreach ($result as $row) {
        $name = $row['question_body'];

      }
      mysqli_close($db);
    }
  ?>

  <form name="editQ" method="POST" action="edit.php" > 
    <td>Please Edit the Question</td> 
    <input type="text" name="<?php echo ($q)?>" value="<?php
            echo htmlspecialchars($name);?>" /> 
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Edit">
  </form>
```

Any help/advice would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: whats there in your query string .?

Comment: Why not use pdo libraries with prepared statement?

Comment: @nana.chorage what do you mean?

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Please, do not use `sprintf`, it's a flimsy, error-prone alternative.

Comment: @Marco Mura I am using (mysqli)

Comment: James: what you are passing in query string .

Answer (score 2):

Your form is sending POST and you're trying to get values using GET.

Answer (score 0):

`$id` is not being set before the SQL statement is being called. It's in the `else` section of the `if` statement `isset($_GET['editQ'])` which defines `$id`;

Also instead of `foreach` use the following with a mysqli result

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    // STUFF
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't initialize $id if it is not set in $_GET['editQ']. If however in that case you still need it, I guess you know some default id for that instance. Define it then at the top of the script in case it is later not overwritten by $_GET value.

Answer (score 0):

Try pulling the `$id` assignment outside the `if` statement:

```
<?php
  $name = '';


  if (isset($_GET['editQ'])) {
    $ok = true;
    $id = $_GET['editQ'];

    if ($ok) {
        // add database code here
        $db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'test2015');
        $sql = sprintf("UPDATE question SET question_body='%s'
          WHERE question_id=%s",
          mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $name),
          $id);
        mysqli_query($db, $sql);
        echo '<p>User updated.</p>';
        mysqli_close($db);
    }
    else {
      $db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'test2015');
      $sql = sprintf('SELECT * FROM question WHERE question_id=%s', $id);
      $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
      foreach ($result as $row) {
        $name = $row['question_body'];
      }
      mysqli_close($db);
    }
  }
?>
```

---

Edit: the above code clears the unset variable error, but the user is still working on distinguishing `$id` from `$editQ`.

Comment: Thanks for the help,This gets rid of the error messages. However, the value in the database still stays empty when I am trying to update the value.

Comment: Do you think it is related to the line `$name = '';`?  Maybe try `$name = 'test_name';`

Comment: Tried $name = 'test_name';
this will update the value in the database with test_name

Comment: I'd like to add that I am new to PHP, i apologise for silly questions/comments

Comment: @james: No silly questions!  We were all new once  :-)  Maybe I don't understand what you're trying to do.  `UPDATE question SET question_body='%s' WHERE question_id=%s...$name, $id...` should be updating row `$id` so field question_body equals `$name`.  Maybe try changing `mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $name)` to `mysqli_real_escape_string($name)`?

Comment: Tried that as well but unfortunately that does not work either. What I am trying to do is when the user types something in the textbox then the value  written in the textbox should be updated in the database.

Comment: Is the user text stored in `$editQ` or another variable?

Comment: Ahh, right now you are telling MySQL to update the row where `question_id` equals whatever the user input (which you assign to `$id`).  For now, change the line to `$sql = sprintf("UPDATE question SET question_body='%s'
          WHERE question_id=1",
          mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['editQ']));`  Obviously you will want to change the "1" to the correct actual id, but this will get you started.